# asp.net FileUpload 'open' click to copy title

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I am using a asp.net FileUpload control to upload files. There is a 'Title' text box which allows user to enter file title as well. The 'Upload' button then uploads the file to the server. This is all working fine. My problem however is that, customer has asked to copy the file name automatically to the title 'text box' in case user wants the custom title to be the same as file name.

Unfortunately, I am unable to figure this one out. I thought there would be an event behind the 'open' button of the file upload, that I could tap into and just as the title gets displayed on the fileupload control, similarly it should also get displayed on my title text box field. Perhaps Javascript/JQuery might help.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Why not simply allow the user to leave the title blank, and use the file name when you process the upload?

Comment: Thats a work around I thought, but there may be times when the customer wants to append or prefix the existing title. Some files have very big titles so its cumbersome to type in the same thing again or modified title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the input's `change` event with jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('input:file').on('change', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    })
})
```

You will probably have to parse the value to remove the "fakepath" stuff that some browsers add.

You can do this using the `split` method:

```
var title = $(this).val().split('\\');
console.log(title[title.length - 1])
```